# Coldfusion cfpdfform with LiveCycle

Tags: coldfusion, attributes, livecycle, cfpdfform

I am using `<cfpdfform>` to populate a LiveCycle Designer developed pdf form.  I've excluded the destination attribute and the pdf shows in the browser exactly as I wish.  However, it provides a filename of a series of numbers followed `by=temp.pdf`.

Is there any way to provide a variable name for the displayed file?

For example, if I provide a `#URL.name#` in my form submission, I would like the filename displayed in the browser to be `smith.pdf` or whatever name I place in the `#URL.name#`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need below. I once had to create a pdf document using `cfdocument` and I used the below to specify the filename to render as. The caveat is that i had to save the file on the file system first which i achieved with same `cfdocument`.

note `path_to_pdf_file_on_server` and `name_to_render_as.pdf` in the code below

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=name_to_render_as.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="path_to_pdf_file_on_server" deletefile="Yes">
```

Comment: Re: *had to save the file on the file system* You could also save it to a variable via the `result` attribute. Then use `<cfcontent variable="...">`.

Comment: True at that. Never considered. Thanks. Time to update my code. :)

Comment: @Leigh you mind acknowledging the fact that my answer is helpful by upping the vote? Thanks.

Comment: Leigh, the result attribute is not available when using the populate attribute of cfpdfform.

Comment: Hm.. I may have been thinking of the undocumented `name` attribute. If cfpdfform does not support it (which is silly, btw) you may need to save it to a physical file or possibly `ram://`.